# ALTER USER giving Syntax Error

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, jet

I'm creating my own form to allow a user to change their password in a Microsoft Access database with user-level security, an *.mdb file.  When I run the following VBA code, I get error *3293: Syntax error in ALTER TABLE statement*.

`CurrentDb().Execute "ALTER USER user PASSWORD NewPassword OldPassword"`

I'm following the instructions found in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197012(v=office.14).aspx).
How do we change a password through VBA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CurrentDb.Execute` is a DAO method, but `ALTER USER` must be executed from ADO.

```sql
Dim strSql As String
strSql = "ALTER USER user PASSWORD NewPassword OldPassword"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql
```

`CurrentProject.Connection.Execute` is an ADO method.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast response!  It works quite well!  I didn't know that such DDL methods had to be executed through ADO.  I have learned.

Comment: Jet 4 added many features to Access SQL.  ADO was updated to support them but DAO was not.  My personal rule is to use ADO for all Access DDL ... that way I don't need to keep track of which DDL features actually are supported in DAO.